# How can I install these packages?

Tags: r, rstudio, cran

```
install.packages("graphlayouts")

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
             binary source needs_compilation
graphlayouts  0.7.1  0.8.0              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
package 'graphlayouts' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning message:
"cannot remove prior installation of package 'graphlayouts'"Warning message in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE):
"problem copying C:\Anaconda\envs\r-tutorial\Lib\R\library\00LOCK\graphlayouts\libs\x64\graphlayouts.dll to C:\Anaconda\envs\r-tutorial\Lib\R\library\graphlayouts\libs\x64\graphlayouts.dll: Permission denied"Warning message:
"restored 'graphlayouts'"

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpsLQikc\downloaded_packages
```

Comment: Close your R session, navigate to `C:\Anaconda\envs\r-tutorial\Lib\R\library` and delete the folder 00LOCK. Then open Rstudio and try installing the package again.

Comment: I would not recommend mixing cran with conda package managers. These systems tend to interfere with each other, resulting in shared libraries not been seen by one of them (graphlayouts.dll in your case)

Comment: C:\Anaconda\envs\r-tutorial\Lib\R\library I do not see this specific folder.